# JavaFX: Clearing the ListView

Tags: listview, javafx

I want to clear all content from the ListView when I click on some button. I was trying to remove it by indices but it was giving me exceptions. I don't quite get the SelectionModel of ListView. Here are my attempts:

```
asiLogsListView.getSelectionModel().selectAll();
        ObservableList<Integer> indices = asiLogsListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
        for(int index : indices) {
            asiLogsListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().remove(index);
        }
```

or

```
asiLogsListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().removeAll(indices);
```

Comment: Clear all content (all items) or just clear the selection?

Comment: Clear all items. That's why I tried selectAll(). I want clean ListView, but right now it adds up data continuously.

Comment: OK, I missed the `selectAll()` call. You don't need to work with the selection at all to do that; see posted answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To clear all the items from a `ListView`, just do

```
asiLogsListView.getItems().clear();
```

If you want to clear the selection, then do

```
asiLogsListView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

The tricky one is removing all the selected items from the `ListView`:

```
List<Integer> selectedItemsCopy = new ArrayList<>(asiLogsListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
asiLogsListView.getItems().removeAll(selectedItemsCopy);
```

Your code looks like it is trying to clear the selection, because you are trying to remove all the elements from the `selectionModel`'s `selectedItems` list. The problem is that as you remove each item, the index of the remaining items would change, so you end up removing the wrong items, and potentially may end up with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s (if you end up with fewer items than the largest index of a selected item).

Answer (score 3):

The original problem is next: ListView.getSelectionMode() returns part of it's observable list but not the copy. So removing from that list leads to various issues.

Use next code which copies list before removing items from it:

```
sendRightButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        ObservableList<String> potential = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList( //copy
                candidatesListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
        if (potential != null) {
            heroes.addAll(potential);
            candidates.removeAll(potential);
            candidatesListView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
    }
});
```

For more detail : http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24367

Comment: I've already seen this code and did not quite understand it. I don't need copy, when I click button, I don't need that data any more. Btw, you're talking about getSelectionMode(), and code shows getSelectionModel(). Both functions exist so which one is it? :D

Comment: This code (it is `getSelectionModel()`, not `getSelectionMode()`) removes all the selected items from the list view. You need to make a copy of the list of selected items, because that list is just a view of a sub list of the items in the list view. If you don't make a copy of that list, it causes problems because the list over which you are iterating changes as you iterate over it.