# Java + JavaFX: does it make sense to periodically clear a ListView content on the long run?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'll try to give a more accurate insight about my question.

Let's say I've a JavaFX ListView which I keep populating with my console output through a background thread, which doesn't burden on my GUI: the output is quite heavy, with a lot of messages received every minute.
Will I put my application in a problematic memory load situation if I don't occasionally clear the head (i.e.: the oldest output) of my ListView? 
During my tests I haven't noticed any sensible change in the RAM occupation of my application, but I think I'll probably notice that in a long run execution.

To be honest, here on StackOverflow I haven't found any post satisfying my question. Moreover, I've only found questions asking about how to clear ALL the ListView content (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206854/javafx-clearing-the-listview)), but not partially with a cyclic task (maybe triggered by a timer?).

Thank you for any insight, feedback and/or documentation you may be able to give me back.

Comment: Here is my guess: Given that today's computers have lots of memory, I wouldn't worry much about it. Also due to the way ListView is implemented, you should not run into any GUI problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ListView` is backed by a list, called its `items` list. You can add as many items to that list; but note that you will not overburden the memory footprint of the UI as the implementation of the `ListView` works by using a (more or less) fixed set of "cells" and reusing them to display new data as, for example, the user scrolls the view.

That said, of course if you continue adding more items to the list without restriction, then it will use more memory, and eventually result in a `OutOfMemoryError`. You can test this easily enough with something like

```
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
int count = 0 ;
while (true) {
    listView.getItems().add("Item "+(++count));
}
```

which will, of course, exhaust memory quickly.

If you are adding lots of items to the list, and you expect the application to run for a while (which is essentially possible for any desktop app - I run Chrome and Eclipse on my laptop for months at a time), then you should limit the number of items in the list. This is easy enough to do, just remove items from the front of the list if adding them would exceed some maximum value. E.g.

```
public class Controller {

    private static final int MAX_LIST_VIEW_ITEMS = 5_000 ;

    private ObservableList<String> listData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView ;

    public void initialize() {
        listView.setItems(listData);
        // ...
    }

    public void addToListView(List<String> itemsToAdd) {
        listData.addAll(itemsToAdd);
        int excess = itemsToAdd.size() - MAX_LIST_VIEW_ITEMS ;
        if (excess > 0) {
            listData.subList(0, excess).clear();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation, thank you. In a few words, Java ListViews work just like the ListViews in Android, adding the fact they automatically recycle the old ones. I'll implement the code to limit the items in my application.